# SSIS - Excel to txt file: how to obtain the same formatting as 'Results to Text' in SSMS?

Tags: ssis, flat-file, dataflowtask

I am creating a data flow with excel source and flat file destination.

When I create the flat file connection manager with the "Delimited" format I have no problems creating the txt file.
If I try instead to use the "Fixed width" (like it happens with "Results to Text" in SSMS) I keep getting erros like this one: [image]
when I am in the "Columns" tab.

Also, when I try to run the package it tells me that "It's impossible to write the name of the column "this_column". It could be that the name of the column is bigger than the available column dimensions."
How can I make each column as long as the longest value?

Comment: Did you select an existing file when creating the flat file connection manager, or did you just type in the name of a new file?  Also, was there sample data in the excel, when creating this?

Comment: I typed in the name of a new file when creating the flat file connection manager.
Yes, there is data  in the excel file